# How to count repeated word in string

Tags: tcl

I have string for example:

```
Test
Test
Test
Something
Something
```

And I want to calculate how many times this string repeats.

Result will be:

```
Test 3
Something 2
```

Can anyone have idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc countwords {str} {
    foreach word [split $str] {incr count($word)}
    foreach word [array names count] {puts "$word $count($word)"}
}

set string {Test
Test
Test
Something
Something}

countwords $string
```

```
Test 3
Something 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To know how many times a *specific* word repeats in a string:

```
regexp -all {\yTest\y} $theString
```

To count for *all* words:

```
foreach word [regexp -all -inline {\w+} $theString] {
    incr histogram($word)
}
parray histogram
```